# PrimeFaces Terminal refreshing a String Stream

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

is there anyway to use PrimeFaces terminal to show a stream of text? Something like if I want it to behave like Unix "tail -f " command that will show+refresh string data as it comes.

If it is not possible, any other recommendations on how to achieve this in an JSF2 page?

Thanks,
Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

No there is not. That is not what the terminal is for. Just use PrimeFaces push to append text to some div at each update. Look at the PrimeFaces Push showcase of the ['chat' example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml)